# Transition probability for a time dependant probability

Tags: probability

I have some questions about events like :

$$P((\sigma_1, t_1),(\sigma_2,t_2))$$

The signification is : "there is an event $\sigma_1$ at time $t_1$ AND an event $\sigma_2$ at time $t_2$ (we can rewrite it as $P((\sigma_1, t_1) \cap(\sigma_2,t_2))$".

The first question I have is the following.

We know that we can write :

$$P(\sigma', t')=\sum_{\sigma} P(\sigma,t) P((\sigma,t) \rightarrow (\sigma',t')),$$

where $P((\sigma,t) \rightarrow (\sigma',t'))$ is the transition probability from $(\sigma,t)$ to $(\sigma',t')$.

But I don't know how to rigorously prove it.

**Actually, for me it seems to be general but it is probably only true for Markov chain. But as I don't know how to prove it rigorously I'm not sure of it is general or not**

---

Tentative of proof (with mistakes) :

I consider $A=(\sigma,t)$, $B=(\sigma',t')$ I would have:

$$P(A,B)=P(B)P(A \mid B)$$

Thus: $$P(B)=\sum_A P(A,B)=\sum_A P(A)P(B \mid A)$$

Thus: $$P(\sigma', t')=\sum_{(\sigma,t)} P(\sigma,t) P((\sigma,t) \rightarrow (\sigma',t'))$$

**However, as you can see, my sum is thus on all the $(\sigma,t)$ and not only on all the $\sigma$**.

This is the thing that is confusing me a lot actually.

Where is my mistake? I think it is linked to the rigorous definition of an event but I am not sure.

I am a big beginner in probability theory and I need to understand some Markov chains for practice purpose. So i would like to stay around the definitions if possible.

Answer (score 1):

At fixed time $t$, the sets $((\sigma,t))_\sigma$ form a partition (any trajectory has a well defined state at time $t$). By the law of total probabilty, for any event $A$,
$$P(A)=\sum_{\sigma} P(A \cap (\sigma,t))=\sum_\sigma P(A|(\sigma,t))P(\sigma,t),$$
so in case $A=(\sigma',t')$, we have 
$$P((\sigma',t'))= \sum_\sigma P((\sigma,t)\to(\sigma',t'))P((\sigma,t)),$$
where the sum is only on $\sigma$.

This is valid even if the chain is not Markov, as we did not use this assumption.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. So in a sense, can I say to define things properly that : $t$ is an external parameter for the probability. $\sigma$ is an event. By definition the sum on all event of a probability gives 1 : $\sum_{\sigma} P(\sigma,t)=1$. So, said differently, $t$ is just an external parameter that the probability depends on but it is not part of the event, the event is "just" $\sigma$. And then because the event is properly defined i just use the basic probabilities properties.

Comment: So maybe the probability should be written (to be more clear) : $P(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)_{t_1, t_2}$ to show that the $t_i$ are just parameters (not linked with the notion of event).